# Independence of two events

Tags: probability

In Durrett’s [Essentials of Stochastic Processes](http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/EOSP/EOSP2E.pdf) (2nd edition), there is an example on basic probability on page 209.

> *Example A.6.* Roll two dice and let A = "the first die is 4."
>   Let $B_1$ = "the second die is 2."
>
> $P(A \cap B_1) = \frac 1 {36} \neq \frac 1 6 \cdot \frac 4 {36} = P(A)P(B_1) $

Where did $\frac 4 {36}$ come from? I thought that $P(A) = P(B_1) = \frac 1 6$.

Comment: It would work if $B_1$ were the event "the sum is $5$."

Comment: I checked the book and I think is a mistake, since he wanted first to exemplify a case where events ARE independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is indeed the example then it is very peculiar indeed. Both $P(A)$ and $P(B_1)$ are equal to $\frac{1}{6}$, and the events are independent. I don't have the book so you might want to double check everything regarding that example, or look for errata.